# Docker Multi-container connection with docker compose

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, devops

### I am trying to create a composition where two or more docker service can connect to each other in some way.

Here is my composition.

```
# docker-compose.yaml

version: "3.9"

services:
  database:
    image: "strapi-postgres:test"
    restart: "always"
    ports:
      - "5435:5432"

  project:
    image: "strapi-project:test"
    command: sh -c "yarn start"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "1337:1337"
    env_file: ".env.project"
    depends_on:
      - "database"
    links:
      - "database"
```

### Services

#### `database`

This is using a Image that is made with of Official Postgres Image.

Here is Dockerfile

```
FROM postgres:alpine
ENV POSTGRES_USER="root"
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD="password"
ENV POSTGRES_DB="strapi-postgres"
```

and using the default exposed port `5432` and forwarding to `5435` as defined in the **Composition**.

So the `database` service starts at some **IPAddress** that can be found using `docker inspect`.

#### `project`

This is a Image running a node application(strapi project configured to use postgres database).

Here is Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
WORKDIR /project
ADD package*.json .
ADD yarn.lock .
RUN npm install 
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 1337
```

and I am builing the Image using `docker build`. That gives me an Image with *No Foreground Process*.

#### Problems

1. When I was running the composition, the `strapi-project` container *Exits with Error Code(0)*.

Solution: So I added command `yarn start` to run the Foreground Process.

2. As the `project` Starts it could not connect to `database` since it is trying to connect to `127.0.0.1:5432` (5432 since it should try to connect to the container port of `database` service and not 5435). This is not possible since this tries to connect to port `5432` inside the container `strapi-project`, which is not open for any process.

Solution: So I used the IPAddress that is found from the `docker inspect` and used that in a `.env.project` and passed this file to the project service of the **Composition**.

3. For Every `docker compose up` there is a incremental pattern(n'th time 172.17.0.2, n+1'th time 172.18.0.2, and so on) for the IPAddress of the *Composition*. So Everytime I run composition I need to edit the `.env.project`.

##### All of these are some hacky way to patch them together. I want some way to Create the Postgres `database` service to start first and then `project` to configure, connect, and  to the database, start automatically.

Suggest me any edits, or other ways to configure them.

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten to put the `CMD` in your Dockerfile, which is why you get the "exited (0)" status when you try to run the container.

```bash
FROM node:lts-alpine
...
CMD yarn start
```

[Compose automatically creates a Docker network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) and each service is accessible using its Compose container name as a host name.  You never need to know the container-internal IP addresses and you pretty much never need to run `docker inspect`.  (Other answers might suggest manually creating `networks:` or overriding `container_name:` and these are also unnecessary.)

You don't show where you set the database host name for your application, but an `environment:` variable is a common choice.  If your database library doesn't already honor the [standard PostgreSQL environment variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html) then you can reference them in code like `process.env.PGHOST`.  Note that the host name will be different running inside a container vs. in your normal plain-Node development environment.

A complete Compose file might look like

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  database:
    image: "strapi-postgres:test"
    restart: "always"
    ports:
      - "5435:5432"

  project:
    image: "strapi-project:test"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "1337:1337"
    environment:
      - PGHOST=database
    env_file: ".env.project"
    depends_on:
      - "database"
```